# Double Summation using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I'm trying to do a double summation for a quite complicated formula in R, but I don't think the for loops are working as I'd expect.

Here's just a basic version of something for complicated I'm trying to do.

\sum_{I=3}^{5}\sum_{j=2}^{3} (I*j)

I'd hope this would sum all the terms together like 3*2+3*3+4*2+4*3+5*2+5*3
which would give 60. However the code I have doesn't produce that so wondering what R is actually doing with this double for loop.

```
 for(i in 3:5){
 for(j in 2:3){
   x<-i*j
     }
    }
```

I know this example is trivial but if I can understand this hopefully will be able to apply it to more complicated thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can use built in functions, for example `sum(outer(3:5, 2:3, "*"))`

Comment: You need `x = x + i*j`    and initialize x to 0

Comment: Currently, your `for` loop is just re-writing your `x` object over and over, which the last one just happens to be `x <- 5*3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add x to each loop:

```
x <- 0
for(i in c(3,4,5)){
  for(j in c(2,3)){
    x <- x + i*j # add x here
  }
}
x
```

EDIT: this is the same as what @G5W said

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
x <- 3:5
y <- 2:3
```

you can approach it as

```
out <- integer()
for(i in x){
  for(j in y){
    out <- c(out, i*j)
  }
}
sum(out)
```

or, as the above accrues the vector (which might be expensive), alternatively

```
with(expand.grid(x, y), sum(Var1*Var2))
```

or

`sum(x %o% y)` which is another way for `sum(outer(x,y))`